# pyplot doesn't save graph to file

Tags: python

For some reason this doesn't save my plot. It only displays it.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("volvo_volvo.csv");
dfw = pandas.DataFrame(data = df, columns=['PriceDisplay','Year','Odometer'])
y = df.PriceDisplay.values
x = df.Odometer.values


plt.scatter(x,y,linewidth=2)
plt.show()
fig.savefig('fig2.png')
```

Comment: where is your `fig` object defined?